# Programmatically change the "Use by default for this action"

Tags: android

I have the normal 'Phone' dialer and I have new 'Dialer' app. Now if I check the "Use by default for this action" and click on the 'Dialer' app then every time when I press the phone button the 'Dialer' app will be started automatically. But how can I change this in code ?

Where this preference is stored ?

And how is this mapped ? is this is mapped by an android action intent string ?

for example the Intent.ACTION_CALL is paired with some application for example the 'Dialer' app to be the default app that will be started every time the Intent.ACTION_CALL it is raised...

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting from API 21 you can use next intent to ask user to be a default dialer:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
        .putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER);
    } else {
      Log.w(getLocalClassName(), "No Intent available to handle action");
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't change default applications using a app
but you can referr via intent to the settings page of an app to set the defaults

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.Aplications);
startActivity(i);
```

or something like this

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3043): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.Settings.Applications }
 is thrown

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
startActivity(i);

Comment: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ALL_APPS }
 am I missing some permission ? have you ever tried this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void chnagedialer() {
        TelecomManager systemService = this.getSystemService(TelecomManager.class);
        if (systemService != null && !systemService.getDefaultDialerPackage().equals("com.android.contacts")) {
            startActivity((new Intent(ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)).putExtra(EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME,"com.android.contacts" ));
        }

    }
```