# Programmatically choose the phone's original default dialer instead of any other options

Tags: java, android, call

When I try to make a call from my app using

```
intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode));
startActivity(intent);
```

I get the option

[image: option]

I want to programmatically choose the dialer that the user will use to make the call. I want the user to automatically use Phone (the original dialer) instead of Skype or any other option.

From googling, I found this option below but it only allows the developer to make the user choose the developer's own app as a default dialer. I want to programmatically ask the user to choose the original phone's default dialer "Phone" so that the user is no longer asked the question.

From google, I found this link: [Programmatically change the "Use by default for this action"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158637/programmatically-change-the-use-by-default-for-this-action)

which has this option:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
        .putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER);
    } else {
      Log.w(getLocalClassName(), "No Intent available to handle action");
    }
```

[image: option]

But what I want is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

`Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
startActivity(callIntent);`

it is working for me

Comment: you obviously didn't read my question. I am looking for a way to change the default app used for phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "mobilePhone"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you obviously didn't read my question. I am looking for a way to change the default app used for phone calls.